# Transform Array of Objects (stringified) in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, datatables

I have this object in JavaScript of which the data is from AJAX response:

```
var data1 = [
   {
      "id": "ID1",
      "name": "John"
   },
   {
      "id": "ID2",
      "name": "Mark"
   },
];
```

How do I transform it to something like:

```
var data2 = [["ID1", "John"],["ID2", "Mark"]];
```

I need that format for populating the data to existing empty **DataTables** (**row.add()**).

Thank you for the help.

**Edit:**
I added **"ID1"**, and **"ID2"** to **data2**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the AJAX response is not parsed yet, then make it an Object first

```
data1 = JSON.parse( ajaxResponseStr );
```

Assuming that `data1` is already an Object, simply try

```
data2 = data1.map( function(item){ return [item.name] });
```

Comment: This answer and those below ones are all useful and acceptable but I have to accept only one. To be fair, I'd accept this since this is the first. Thanks, all.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to remove the unwanted fields and turn each object to the specified format, like this:

```js
var data1 = [{
    "id": "ID1",
    "name": "John"
  },
  {
    "id": "ID2",
    "name": "Mark"
  },
];

var data2 = data1.map(function(item) {
  return [item["name"]];
});

console.log(data2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array#map` to create an array of names and id.

**EDIT:** OP updated the question. Code edited to return both `id` and `name`.

```js
var data1 = [{"id": "ID1","name": "John"},{"id": "ID2","name": "Mark"}];
var data2 = data1.map(({id, name}) => [id, name]);
console.log(data2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `data1` is an Array, so you can easily use `.map` method on it. 
`.map` method returns an Array of values, you return from callback.

```
data2 = data1.map(function(item) { return [item.name]});
```

Answer (score 1):

basing on your data structure, coding like this:

```
var data2 = [];
for(var i in data1){
    data2.push(data1[i].name)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

**ES6:**

```
const data2 = data1.map(({ name }) => [name]);
```

**ES5:**

```
var data2 = data1.map(function(item) {
   return [item.name];
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Or using `Array.prototype.reduce()`;

```js
var data1 = [
   {
      "id": "ID1",
      "name": "John"
   },
   {
      "id": "ID2",
      "name": "Mark"
   },
];

var data2 = data1.reduce(function(accum, item) { accum.push([item.name]); return accum; }, []);
console.log(data2);
```